# Azure ARM template not defined?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

New to Azure, creating a very basic ARM template. Can someone tell me why i'm constantly receiving the below error:
"Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vNet' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)"

I've tried removing the "DependsOn" entries to no avail.

Thanks!

{

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "VMname": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the VM"
        }
    },
    "vNet": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 10,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Virtual Network"
        }
    },
    "StorageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 50,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of Storage Account"
        }
    }        
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
"resources": [{
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "name": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]"
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "kind": "Storage"
},

{
    "name": "VMname-PublicIP",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
    "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
    },
    "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
            "domainNameLabel": "[toLower('VMname')]"
        }
    }
},
{
    "name": "VMname-nsg",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
            {
                "name": "nsgRule1",
                "properties": {
                    "description": "description",
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "sourcePortRange": "*",
                    "destinationPortRange": "3389",
                    "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "priority": 100,
                    "direction": "Inbound"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "name": "[parameters('vNet')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', 'VMname-nsg')]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "vNet"
    },
    "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
                "10.0.0.0/16"
            ]
        },
        "subnets": [
            {
                "name": "vNet-Subnet",
                "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "networkSecurityGroup": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', 'VMname-nsg')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "name": "VMname-NetworkInterface",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
    "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'VMname-PublicIP')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vNet')]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "VMname Network Interface"
    },
    "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "ipConfig1",
                "properties": {
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                    "publicIPAddress": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'VMname-PublicIP')]"
                    },
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'vNet', 'vNet-Subnet')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "name": "[parameters('VMname')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', toLower('StorageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', 'VMname-NetworkInterface')]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "VMname"
    },
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_A2_v2"
        },
        "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "VMname",
            "adminUsername": "adminUsername",
            "adminPassword": "adminPassword"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                "offer": "WindowsServer",
                "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "name": "VMnameOSDisk",
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage"
            }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', 'VMname-NetworkInterface')]"
                }
            ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
            "bootDiagnostics": {
                "enabled": true,
                "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', toLower('StorageAccountName'))).primaryEndpoints.blob]"
            }
        }
    }
}],
"outputs": {}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vNet')]"
```

should be this:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vNet'))]"
```